# php preg match regex ahref url

Tags: php

i use scraper for get a href from result web, i get this :

```
href="/url?q=https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr/signup/index%3Frealm_key%3Deuw&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiuzqft5trSAhXBPRoKHbpXDMUQjBAIHjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNEYfGG0WY7wMdmBC-sxVjOWeUliXg"

/url?q=https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr/signup/index%3Frealm_key%3Deuw&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiuzqft5trSAhXBPRoKHbpXDMUQjBAIHjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNEYfGG0WY7wMdmBC-sxVjOWeUliXg

href="/url?q=http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr/news/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiuzqft5trSAhXBPRoKHbpXDMUQjBAIIDAC&amp;usg=AFQjCNExC7Mbonp2YirFtmf4gMFAjvA03A"

...
```

i get only href by this :

```
preg_match("/href=\"(.*?)\"/i", $test, $matches);
```

But i don't find how get only url between "/url?q" and "&amp"

i have tried like this but doesn't work i have no result :

```
preg_match("/href=/url?q\"(.*?)\"/i", $test, $matches);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick

preg_match("/href=\"\/url\?q\=(.*)\"/i", $test, $matches);

Comment: thans but i have an error with this : Unknown modifier 'r'.

Comment: in my original post the backslahs in front of the /url was gone, double check if it is present in yours

Comment: that work nice, but now how regex for don't get url after "&amp", i have try this but i failed : preg_match("/href=\"\/url\?q\=(.*)\"\$\amp\/i", $test, $matches);

Comment: preg_match("/href=\"\/url\?q\=([^&]*)/")

Answer (score 1):

perhaps it would be better to obtain the href and then explicitly parse the URL as:

```
<?php

$s = '/url?q=http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr/news/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiuzqft5trSAhXBPRoKHbpXDMUQjBAIIDAC&amp;usg=AFQjCNExC7Mb';

$arr = array();

//first, get the query string
$qs = parse_url(html_entity_decode($s));

//parse query string and isolate the parameter 'q'
parse_str($qs['query'], $arr);

print($arr['q']);

?>
```

this yields `http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr/news/`

Answer (score 1):

its working fine

```
 <?php
    $url='href="/url?q=https://signup.euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr/signup/index%3Frealm_key%3Deuw&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiuzqft5trSAhXBPRoKHbpXDMUQjBAIHjAD&amp;usg=AFQjCNEYfGG0WY7wMdmBC-sxVjOWeUliXg"';
    preg_match('/href="(.*)"/', $url, $matches);

    print_r($matches[1]);
    ?>
```

Comment: that give me : /url?q=http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjznuS27trSAhUDVxoKHVbMCP0QFggcMAA&amp;usg=AFQjCNFaXRUpTH-pRn_NkoRrJM0KkVnFjA
its better but i needed to had just : http://euw.leagueoflegends.com/fr, how reger for get this without url?q and don't have the result after "&amp"

Comment: preg_match('/signup(.*)index/', $url, $matches);